# Messages from the server doesn't show up in the textView, but works fine with NSlog

Tags: objective-c, sockets, textview

I am about to eat my keyboard now.
I wrote a program to send and receive messages from server. There is no problem with sending message. But when I try to use the textView to show all messages, there are only messages which I sent show up.

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode{
NSLog(@"stream event %i", eventCode);
switch (eventCode) {
    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        NSLog(@"Stream opened");
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        if (aStream == inPutStream) {
            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            int len;
            while ([inPutStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                len = [inPutStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if (len > 0) {
                    Message = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer
                                                       length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                    [self recvMessage:Message];
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        ;
}
}

- (void)recvMessage:(NSString *)output{
self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",self.textView.text,output];
}
```

and this is the header

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSStreamDelegate>
- (IBAction)backGround2:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backGround:(id)sender;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFeild;
- (IBAction)sendBotton:(id)sender;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *hostName;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *MainView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *chatView;
- (IBAction)connectBotton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)disConnect:(id)sender;

@end

NSString *Message;
NSInputStream *inPutStream;
NSOutputStream *outPutStream;
```

Everything works fine except for showing the message from server. But when I change:

```
[self.recvMessage:Message` to `NSLog(@"%@",Message)
```

I can see the message in Target Output.

The client running on server has definitely sent the message.

Comment: check the TextView outlet is given or not in Xib.

Comment: yea its there and always there never run away lol  thanks anyways

Comment: it seems like i cannot make any change to the ui when its in the run-loop im so confused

Comment: try to print output in recvMessage function

Comment: works good, i see the reply from server

Comment: 2013-05-31 01:37:54.933 [779:c07] stream event 1
2013-05-31 01:37:54.934 [779:c07] Stream opened
2013-05-31 01:37:54.934 [779:c07] stream event 1
2013-05-31 01:37:54.935 [779:c07] Stream opened
2013-05-31 01:37:54.935 [779:c07] stream event 4
2013-05-31 01:37:55.091 [779:c07] stream event 2
2013-05-31 01:37:55.851 [779:c07] Greetingfromserver

Comment: Thank you for your helping but i need to sleep for now... maybe tomorrow morning i will come back.. goodnight

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- (void)recvMessage:(NSString *)output
{
        if ([txtvw.text length] > 0)
        {
            txtvw.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", txtvw.text, output];
        }
        else
        {
            txtvw.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", output];
        }
}
```

Comment: try my updated ans, if not works then just set some demo text to textview like textView.text = @"test";, if it works then my ans surely works for u.

Comment: i use soryboard and there are two viewcontrollers in there. will this makes any sense ?

Comment: no it does not make an sense, just comment above code & set some demo text like textView.text = @"test";

Comment: means your outlet is not set properly.

Comment: but i have another button which can change the string in the textView works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a threading issue, where the networking happens on a background thread, and you're therefore not updating on the UI (i.e. main) thread.

You could try this for a quick fix. Replace:

```
[self recvMessage:Message];
```

with

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(recvMessage:) withObject:Message waitUntilDone:NO];
```

or the equivalent gcd variant.